# Running QTP tests on a remote desktop (Vmware machine) from ALM

Tags: qtp, hp-quality-center, alm

I am trying to execute tests on a remote desktop (Vmware machine) from QC.

Below are the steps that I have followed,

- QTP installed on Remote Machines
- QTP Add-in is installed in QC and QTP machine.
- QC connectivity Add-in is installed in QC and QTP machine.
- Settings done in QTP to allow other HP products to execute.
- Set the DCOM Configuration Properties on Remote Machine
- Connection to QC from QTP is made default with correct domain and valid credentials.
- Defined host machine in the Host Manager of QC
- All the function libraries and repositories are accessible from all machines.

RDP's are Windows 7 machines with ALM 11 + QTP 11

When I try to Kick off a test from a machine with QC & QTP installed, it works fine & the test is triggered successfully on the Remote Desktop.

The issue I am having is when I try to kick off a test, from a machine which doesn't have QTP installed (only QC is insatlled on this machine) - When I try this QC is unable to launch QTP on the remote machine.

I am using  "***Set qtApp = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application", "MyServer")***" to create Application Object.

Do we need to have QTP installed on the machine where you are trying to kick off tests from?

Thanks,
Shaun

Answer (score 1):

Nope - you should be able to kick off tests remotely. I do it all the time.